# Strange bug whilst multiplying unsigned integer by 10 in C

Tags: c, gcc, multiplication

I have run into a strange bug where a multiplication is giving the wrong result. Below is a simplified version which gives the same result on my system.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("%u\n", 1111111111U*10U);
}
```

I am compiling with GCC 4.7.1 on OpenSUSE 12.2 (3.4.11-2.16-default x86_64) and this gives me the following output:

```
2521176518
```

Comment: You can find more explanation of BlackBear's comment [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: There is no overflow in the OP's program.

Comment: The only strange thing is that the compiler does not emit a warning. If you supply a literal that does not fit into an integer, it does warn. However, apparently when you multiply two literals together (which, too, is a literal), and the result is too large, it doesn't bother.

Comment: @BlackBear: Not exactly. C11 6.2.5/9: *"[...] **A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow**,
 because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
represented by the resulting type."* (emphasis mine)

Comment: @netcoder good point, I thought that but didn't express myself with the appropriate words :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 * 1.1 billion exceeds the range of an unsigned int on your system, thus you're seeing the overflowed result.

On a 32-bit system, the maximum value an unsigned int can hold is 4294967295 (4.29 billion).

Comment: If I have a 32-bit hardware counter and it counts up to 0xffffffff and then wraps back to 0x00000000, we say the counter "overflowed".  If it had more bits to carry the result into, it would not have overflowed, but it didn't, thus it overflowed.  The *effect* of this is that the result is mod-2^32.  But overflow is the *cause* of the modulo behavior.

Comment: overflow, for me, implies Undefined Behaviour. There is no Undefined Behaviour in the OP's code.

Comment: pmg, it is indeed called [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: overflow is UB with signed ints only. it's well defined with uint

Comment: I prefer to call `modulo 2^32 arithmetic`

Comment: Unsigned integers cannot overflow, the standard says it almost word-for-word, C11 6.2.5/9: *"[...] A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, [...]"*

Comment: So it seems it's all a matter of semantics and interpretation.  It comes down to, "What exactly is meant by the term 'overflow'?".  In many circles, overflow is taken to mean exactly what I've described above.  In other circles, overflow means that "the sign of the result is opposite to what would normally be expected given the operands of an operation."  In still other circles, an overflow is an exception, similar to a SIGSEGV or SIGILL on Linux, that is trapped by the system.  So I'm both right and wrong, depending on the perspective of the circle you live in.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess ... your implementation uses 32 bits `unsigned` values, right?

`unsigned` arithmetic is done modulo 2^32 if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Integer numbers are usually represented as [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). On 32 bit machines the maximum signed integer is `+2147483647/-2147483648` or unsigned `+4294967295`.

When you multiply `1,111,111,111 * 10`, you would get `11,111,111,110`, which is larger then the maximum possible unsigned integer. Thus the [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

With binary representation, this is

```
1000010001110100011010111000111 * 1010 = 1010010110010001100001100111000110
```

The least 32 bits are `10010110010001100001100111000110`, which is `2521176518` decimal.

Comment: @pmg You're right, I was one off. `2^32` instead of `2^32-1`. Fixed.